# Why do 2D drawn frames of anime always have line art and rarely line art in different colors?

Tags: anime-production

Why do 2D hand-drawn frames of anime always have black line art? anime rarely has different colored line art like anime having blue line art? Why do drawn frames of anime always have black line art?

Comment: I don't watch the series, but I distinctly remember that *No Game No Life* uses non-black line art.

Comment: Does [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5378/8486) answer your question?

Comment: no, I was talking about why do line drawings have different colors that animators do when digitally inking drawings on their anime.